# Upload error in Apache server running module mod_fcgid

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, fastcgi

i am running apache server with nginx as reverse proxy on ubuntu 10LTS . i am running php as fast cgi through apache module fcgid. 
When i try to upload a file greater than 16MB it gives me internal server error.
which is

[warn] [client 59.99.25.15] mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 16784462 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (16777216), referer: www..com/upload.php

Means there is problem in fcgid mod so i changed the fcgid.conf present in /etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf

I tried

FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824

and also
MaxRequestLen 1073741824

and still i am getting the same error,please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart your Apache server after adding the FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824.

Comment: I have tried that too and restarted apache server  many times to get it work. But no success. Error log stil shows me the same error,.For your information i am running parallel plesk 11

Comment: I think you need to define MaxRequestLen in /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/domainVirtualHost.php  too.

Comment: After addin here, Reconfigure domains:
/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all

Comment: thanks buddy you really saved my day. i have never used parallels ever. thats why didn't know about the configuration of it. Really thanks again, your answer helped me lot. :) :)

Comment: Its okay...I love this coding stuff !!

Comment: how did you know that , i have to change this file too /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/domainVirtualHost.php